# nginx soap web service settings

Tags: web-services, nginx, soap, wsdl

I have soap service on URL http://webserver:8080/ws/soapService, and if I try get wsdl from  http://webserver:8080/ws/soapService?wsdl it work.
Now, I have problem with nginx, i cant redirect request from http://nginxServer:9090/someSoapService to http://webserver:8080/ws/soapService. My nginx conf is:

```
server {
    listen 9090;
    
    location /someSoapService {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_connect_timeout       10;
            proxy_send_timeout          120;
            proxy_read_timeout          600;
            proxy_pass http://webserver:8080/ws/soapService;
}
```

}

if get wsdl by http://nginxServer:9090/someSoapService?wsdl then nginx return wsdl but, addresses is wrong:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://aa.bb.cc/ws/Types/v1" schemaLocation="http://webserver:8080/ws/soapService?xsd=1"/>
```

...

```
<soap:address location="http://webserver:8080/ws/soapService"/>
```

it should be

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://aa.bb.cc/ws/Types/v1" schemaLocation="http://nginxServer:9090/someSoapService?xsd=1"/>
```

and

```
<soap:address location="http://nginxServer:9090/someSoapService"/>
```

Comment: How did you solve it?